# Time And Date in JSQMessagesViewController in Swift 3

Tags: swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I am having a chat app using `jsqmessangerViewController` everything is working fine but I don't know how to add a date in header and time in chat cell in swift.

Answer (score 0):

**If you want something like this then i have done the following steps.**

> Display date at the top label and add a check to match previous
>       one(if current and previous date is same then do not display
>       otherwise display).

```
let previousMessageObject =
    messageList[indexPath.item-1]
                if (previousMessageObject.messageTime  == currentMessage.messageTime){
                    return CGFloat(kZero)
                }
```

> and for displaying time just append time with message text(use
>   attributed string) and display as simple text. This will serve the
>   purpose

[image]

Comment: Could u help me with top label display because I m getting date in every cell I want date on single page of a particular date and then all messages for that day with date swift @aqsa arshad

Comment: Yes, I would be happy to help.

Comment: You need to check that manually for every message. Match 1-1 dates and return height of top label if date is different, otherwise return zero.